# Array initialization error while passing length value from one Activity to another

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, start-activity

I am new in Android Development.
I am passing a value (`int` type) from an `Activity` using `Intent`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("length", length);  //value is taken from a edit text
startActivity(intent);
```

And then in `NewActivity`, I added this code in `onCreate()` method.

```
arrayLength = getIntent().getIntExtra("length", 0);  //int type arrayLength variabel is diclared globally.
```

And then I am trying to initialize an array on `NewActivity` (out of function)as:

```
char[] array = new char[arrayLength];
```

And then I added array elements in a loop and try to show in a `TextView` using a `Button`.
But it crashes my apps when I click on the `Button` to show array elements with this line of code :

```
arrayElemtsShow.setText(new String (array));
```

> But if I initialize this array with a constant like below, it works fine.

```
char[] array = new char[20];
```

But its important to initialize this array using the value of previous `Activity`.
What can I do to fix this?
And why this is happening?

Logcat:

```
> 2020-06-03 08:43:41.449 30912-30912/? I/.aam.secretnam: Late-enabling
> -Xcheck:jni 2020-06-03 08:43:41.721 30912-30912/com.aam.secretname I/Perf: Connecting to perf service. 2020-06-03 08:43:41.836
> 30912-30912/com.aam.secretname W/.aam.secretnam: Accessing hidden
> method
> Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;->getOpticalInsets()Landroid/graphics/Insets;
> (light greylist, linking) 2020-06-03 08:43:41.836
> 30912-30912/com.aam.secretname W/.aam.secretnam: Accessing hidden
> field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->left:I (light greylist, linking)
> 2020-06-03 08:43:41.836 30912-30912/com.aam.secretname
> W/.aam.secretnam: Accessing hidden field
> Landroid/graphics/Insets;->right:I (light greylist, linking)
> 2020-06-03 08:43:41.836 30912-30912/com.aam.secretname
> W/.aam.secretnam: Accessing hidden field
> Landroid/graphics/Insets;->top:I (light greylist, linking) 2020-06-03
> 08:43:41.836 30912-30912/com.aam.secretname W/.aam.secretnam:
> Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->bottom:I (light
> greylist, linking) 2020-06-03 08:43:41.970
> 30912-30912/com.aam.secretname W/.aam.secretnam: Accessing hidden
> method
> Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z
> (light greylist, reflection) 2020-06-03 08:43:41.973
> 30912-30912/com.aam.secretname W/.aam.secretnam: Accessing hidden
> method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V
> (light greylist, reflection) 2020-06-03 08:43:41.986
> 30912-30912/com.aam.secretname W/.aam.secretnam: Accessing hidden
> method
> Landroid/widget/TextView;->getTextDirectionHeuristic()Landroid/text/TextDirectionHeuristic;
> (light greylist, linking) 2020-06-03 08:43:42.217
> 30912-30938/com.aam.secretname I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build               
> : 4e21c4c, I21281c58c8
>     Build Date                       : 03/01/19
>     OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.25.03.02
>     Local Branch                     : 
>     Remote Branch                    : refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.UM.7.5.R1.09.00.00.464.039
>     Remote Branch                    : NONE
>     Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING 2020-06-03 08:43:42.217 30912-30938/com.aam.secretname I/Adreno: Build Config                 
> : S L 6.0.7 AArch32 2020-06-03 08:43:42.222
> 30912-30938/com.aam.secretname I/Adreno: PFP: 0x005ff110, ME:
> 0x005ff066 2020-06-03 08:43:42.227 30912-30938/com.aam.secretname
> I/ConfigStore:
> android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay
> retrieved: 0 2020-06-03 08:43:42.227 30912-30938/com.aam.secretname
> I/ConfigStore:
> android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay
> retrieved: 0 2020-06-03 08:43:42.227 30912-30938/com.aam.secretname
> I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4 2020-06-03 08:43:42.227
> 30912-30938/com.aam.secretname D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
> 2020-06-03 08:43:42.370 30912-30912/com.aam.secretname
> I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 2924 bytes, containing
> 1 windows, 10 views 2020-06-03 08:43:46.687
> 30912-30912/com.aam.secretname I/Timeline: Timeline:
> Activity_launch_request time:527917018 2020-06-03 08:43:46.728
> 30912-30912/com.aam.secretname W/ActivityThread:
> handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token
> android.os.BinderProxy@22a035f 2020-06-03 08:43:51.641
> 30912-30912/com.aam.secretname D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
> 2020-06-03 08:43:51.645 30912-30912/com.aam.secretname
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>     Process: com.aam.secretname, PID: 30912
>     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
>         at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:402)
>         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6608)
>         at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6585)
>         at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:785)
>         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25919)
>         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6826)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
>      Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>         at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397)
>         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6608) 
>         at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6585) 
>         at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:785) 
>         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25919) 
>         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6826) 
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873) 
>      Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
>         at com.aam.secretname.FirstInput.getLineNumbers(FirstInput.java:71)
>         at com.aam.secretname.FirstInput.line3(FirstInput.java:57)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>         at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397) 
>         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6608) 
>         at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6585) 
>         at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:785) 
>         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25919) 
>         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6826) 
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

first class xml

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="@string/length"
        android:textColor="#66B1F3"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.243" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:ems="10"
        android:background="@drawable/stroke"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/Enterlength"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.122" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
        android:onClick="nextOnClick"
        android:text="@string/btnnext"
        android:background="@drawable/radius_button"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.491"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnexample"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/radius_button"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="@string/examplebtn"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:onClick="exampleOnClick"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.781"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Second class Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_background">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="@string/instruction"
        android:textColor="#2E183E"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.023" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/line_button_background"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="line1"
        android:text="@string/alphabet_1"
        android:textColor="@color/line_color"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView7" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/line_button_background"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="line6"
        android:text="@string/alphabet_6"
        android:textColor="@color/line_color"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/line_button_background"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="line5"
        android:text="@string/alphabet_5"
        android:textColor="@color/line_color"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button6" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/line_button_background"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="line4"
        android:text="@string/alphabet_4"
        android:textColor="@color/line_color"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button7" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/line_button_background"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="line3"
        android:text="@string/alphabet_3"
        android:textColor="@color/line_color"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button8" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/line_button_background"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="line2"
        android:text="@string/alphabet_2"
        android:textColor="@color/line_color"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="150sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/radius_button"
        android:onClick="nextOnClick"
        android:text="@string/btnnext"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/stroke"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/line_numbers"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/back_button"
        android:onClick="reset"
        android:text="@string/reset"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button20"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/radius_button"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="@string/examplebtn"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button9"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

First class

```
package com.aam.secretname;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LengthActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //variables
    int length = 0;
    Intent intent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_length);
    }

    public void nextOnClick(View view) {
        getLength();
        if ((length > 0) && (length < 20)) {
            intent = new Intent(LengthActivity.this, FirstInput.class);
            intent.putExtra("length", length);   //sending value in second activity
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    public void exampleOnClick(View view) {
        TextView showInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        Button example = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnexample);
        showInfo.setText(R.string.example);
        example.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    private void getLength() {
        try {
            EditText wordLength = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            int tempLength = Integer.parseInt(wordLength.getText().toString());

            if ((tempLength<20) && (tempLength>0)) {
                length = tempLength;
            }
            else {
                TextView showInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
                showInfo.setTextColor(Color.RED);

                if (tempLength == 0) showInfo.setText(R.string.warningOfLenthZero);
                else showInfo.setText(R.string.warningOfLengthLimitation);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            TextView showInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
            Button example = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnexample);
            showInfo.setTextColor(Color.RED);

            showInfo.setText(R.string.instuctForGivingLength);
            example.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

Second Class

```
package com.aam.secretname;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class FirstInput extends AppCompatActivity {
    //variables
    int wordLength;
    static int count = 0;
    char[] lineNumbers = new char[wordLength]; //problem
    Intent intent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first_input);
        wordLength = getIntent().getIntExtra("length", 0);  //receiving value of previous activity
    }

    public void nextOnClick(View view) {
        intent = new Intent(FirstInput.this, FinalInput.class);
        if (lineNumbers[wordLength - 1] != '\0'){
            intent.putExtra("lineNumbers", new String(lineNumbers));
            intent.putExtra("length", wordLength); 
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else {
            TextView warning = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
            warning.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            warning.setText(R.string.instuctionForTappingOnLine);
        }
    }

    public void reset(View view) {
        count = 0;
        Arrays.fill(lineNumbers, '\0');
        Toast.makeText(this, "Reseted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        TextView showLineNumbers = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        showLineNumbers.setText("");
    }

    public void line1(View v){
        getLineNumbers('1');
    }
    public void line2(View v){
        getLineNumbers('2');
    }
    public void line3(View v){
        getLineNumbers('3');
    }
    public void line4(View v){
        getLineNumbers('4');
    }
    public void line5(View v){
        getLineNumbers('5');
    }
    public void line6(View v){
        getLineNumbers('6');
    }

    private void getLineNumbers(char line) {
        if(count < wordLength){
            lineNumbers[count++] = line;
            TextView showLineNumbers = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
            showLineNumbers.setText(new String(lineNumbers));
        }
        else{
            TextView showInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
            showInfo.setText(R.string.completedInput);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is data type of length added to intent. As you are taking its value from EditText, that maight be string. So you are adding length as string but getting as int.

Comment: It crashes my app.. Where is the logcat?

Comment: Make sure with debugging that when you pass length in intent, you get the correct value in another activity.

Comment: As i am taking value from TextView I converted string data into int and then passed it to intent. I got correct value from NewActivity.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should provide the exception logcat; but I guess you you missed converting the String to int when you take the value from the EditText

```
intent.putExtra("length", Integer.parseInt(length));
```

> UPDATE:

The problem your problem is that you are initializing the `lineNumbers` array as a member with 0 values; that is because the default `int` value in java is 0.

So, when you use below declaration statement you are assigning a 0-length value to the `lineNumbers` array because `wordLength` is s till 0; so what you need to do is to do this assignment after you `getIntent().getIntExtra()` value.

To do that in code (notice the change marked with `// <<<<<<<<<<<< Change here`)

```
public class FirstInput extends AppCompatActivity {
    //variables
    int wordLength;
    static int count = 0;
    char[] lineNumbers; // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Change here
    Intent intent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first_input);
        wordLength = getIntent().getIntExtra("length", 0);  //receiving value of previous activity
         lineNumbers = new char[wordLength] // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Change here
    }

....
```

Comment: NO i did not missed to convert string into Int. I converted it when taking value. 
Here i added Logcat for you. Thanks

Comment: can you provide the logcat?

Comment: i added Logcat of my project.

Comment: looks like you button click has an issue; how do you use the button listener ?

Comment: Should i provide those classes for you?

Comment: by android:onclick attribute.

Comment: from the logcat there is a problem when you hit a button click ... just make sure you inflate it right and you can share its onClickListener

Comment: Can you share the xml of the button and its callback method?

Comment: i shared logcat and those xml and classes
you may focus on comment written in classes

Comment: @AAM thanks... your problem is that you are intializing the array as a member with 0 values;, and you can't change the length of the array later whenever you retrieve the value from the intent ... to solve this ; move `new char[wordLength];` whenever you get `wordLength` from the intent at LengthActivity

Comment: Yes that's right

Comment: Can you add the solution codes for me?

Comment: Should I pass the value as string and then convert it into int and then use it in array

Comment: No initialize the array in the button click callback method not in class member..

Comment: Sorry to bother. I did not understand what you suggested 6 comments above. Its will be better for me if you write those peice of code in answer

Comment: Sure but now i am writing from my phone.. Give me some hours to explain

Comment: @AAM sorry to be late, I just updated the answer .. wish it targets your query